# How to log in a specifc format in Python using logger?

Tags: python, logging

I am working with Python and I am using `RotatingFileHandler` to log to some file. I have a very simple question

I am logging like this -

```
zooklogger.info("steps:: Actual Steps :: Workflow Path :: Host Path %s %s %s" % (steps, wf_path, status_path))
```

And this is how it is getting logged -

```
steps:: Actual Steps :: Workflow Path :: Host Path [u'step3', u'step2', u'step1'] /re/wf/ius/v1 /re/colo/phx/h1/wf/ius/v1
```

Is there any way that it can be logged as -

```
steps:: Actual Steps :: [u'step3', u'step2', u'step1'], Workflow Path :: /re/wf/ius/v1, Host Path :: /re/colo/phx/h1/wf/ius/v1
```

I know its a pretty silly question to ask but not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just move the `%s` placeholders:

```
zooklogger.info("steps:: Actual Steps :: %s, Workflow Path :: %s, Host Path :: %s" % (steps, wf_path, status_path))
```

The three strings are interpolated into the string at those locations.

Note that you can leave the interpolation step to the `logging` module; it'll postpone interpolating the values to the last moment; that way it doesn't do that work if the log entry never reaches a handler, for example:

```
zooklogger.info("steps:: Actual Steps :: %s, Workflow Path :: %s, Host Path :: %s",
                steps, wf_path, status_path)
```

Here the three arguments are passed in separately to the `logger.info()` call.